# Rails - How to host static assets on S3 with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, production

I have a rails 5 app I'm about to deploy.

the image folder is over 300 Mb (over the limit of heroku's deploy size) So I've uploaded all the images to S3 however, Heroku is still precompiling and the build is failing because of the slug size.

Can anyone point me to articles or help me solve the following problems?

- Precompile Assets and send them to S3
- Use CloudFront with my S3 Bucket (Do I need cloud front?)
- How to Understand bucket policies and how they relate to cloud front / hosting.
- Actually bypass the 300Mb limit of slug size on heroku and get this app deployed

much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Heroku aready had a document about this. Please check it out [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn).

1. You should delete assets files was already in your repo
2. Ignore them from git and push to Heroku
3. Follow above article and check whether it works or not